# Can't Enable Hyper V in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, control-panel

I went to the following path in order to try to enable Hyper V on Windows 10 (Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> Programs and Folders -> Installed Updates -> Turn on Windows features on or off). Once the list populated, Hyper V was a choice but the check box was black and I was not able to enable it (tick the checkbox). I was able to click on the black box within which made it disappear but there was no check. Is this a permissions issue?

Comment: Are you using `Windows 10 N`, `Windows 10 KN`, or `Windows 10 Home` by chance?  You can only enable Hyper-V if you are using `Windows 10 Professional`, `Windows 10 Enterprise`, `Windows 10 Education`, and `Windows 10 LTSB`.  Are you able to provide us a screenshot, of the checkbox being black, because typically checkboxes are either grayed (disabled) or checked or unchecked.  So its unclear what you mean exactly when you say it was black (outside of the obvious description that it's color was black).

Comment: Is your BIOS configured to allow Virtualization?

Comment: Enable vt-x or vt-d in bios settings. And enable developer mode in windows settings.

Answer (score 0):

Enter your BIOS/UEFI and look for something like “Intel VT-x,” “Intel Virtualization Technology”, “Virtualization Extensions" or something similar.

Often, you’ll find the option under a “Processor” submenu. That submenu may be located somewhere under a “Chipset”, “Northbridge”, “Advanced Chipset Control” or “Advanced CPU Configuration” menu.

Enable the option and then save. Then reboot.